# Python AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying replace number to '' blank if the row/column contains numbers. I tried the following it keeps complaing isdigit doesn't exist? I tried converting the column to string and doesn't help. Is there other operators that I could use for the pandas data frame?

```
data = ['123567','1547892','2547879','ABC','3D']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.columns = ['col1']

df1.col1 = str(df1.col1)
if len(df1.col1) < 8 and df1.col1.isdigit(): # errors
    df1.col1 == ''
    print(df1)
```

Looking for an output like this:

```
col1
0   
1   
2   
3   ABC
4   3D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access string methods on a series, you need to do so via [the `.str` attribute of `Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling):

```
df1.col1.str.isdigit()
```

See [`Series.str.isdigit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html#pandas.Series.str.isdigit) for the documentation.

You can use that as a boolean index and directly assign to the selected rows:

```
df1.col1[df1.col1.str.isdigit()] = ''
```

See [*Working with Text Data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

Do not use `df1.col1.str.isdigit()` in an `if` statement, because a boolean array is not True or False by itself, it is an array of boolean values and so would throw `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` if used in a boolean context.

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = ['123567','1547892','2547879','ABC','3D']
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df1.columns = ['col1']
>>> df1
      col1
0   123567
1  1547892
2  2547879
3      ABC
4       3D
>>> df1.col1[df1.col1.str.isdigit()] = ''
>>> df1
  col1
0
1
2
3  ABC
4   3D
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but I got     ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @sharp: I've already shown you in my answer how to do this correctly.

Comment: Thanks it is working now. Not sure why it caused that error before.